# How can Filename too long be avioded in a copy-paste operation?

Tags: copy, copy-and-paste

Im copying some files from one hard drive to another via drag and drop. I got some errors about filenames being too long. Admittedly, the files that wont copy are probably nothing anyone cares about, but still, I have to wonder about how to avoid such problems in the future. [image]

Comment: Related: [How long can file names be?](https://askubuntu.com/q/166764/968501)

Comment: I mean in the context of the question, Im not creating a filename, perse, just copying from one place to another. I assume the length is limited by some amount of memory assigned to the copy function, and that maybe i could change that.

Comment: AFAIK each filesystem ( ie. ext4 ) has a limit in bytes for the filenames that can be created and copying a file involves creating its name in the destination and there is no way to go around this. Rename the file to something shorter then copy it

Answer (score 5):

There is a limit to file name length that cannot be exceeded. This limit differs by the filesystem type and sometimes gets shorter if the filesystem is also encrypted.

You can find out what the limit is on your system by running `getconf NAME_MAX` on a partition like so:

```
getconf NAME_MAX /dev/sda1
```

The output would be the maximum filename length in bytes ( 1 byte = 1 character ) and it will print something like this:

```
255
```

There is a path limit too which you can find by running `getconf PATH_MAX` on a partition like so:

```
getconf PATH_MAX /dev/sda1
```

The output would also be the maximum path length in bytes ( 1 byte = 1 character ) and it will print something like this:

```
4096
```

When copying files, the limit of the destination filesystem is applied as these files will be created in the destination and if their filenames exceed the maximum filename limit for the destination filesystem, the copying process will result in an error and these files will not be copied.

The easy workaround for this is to rename these files to something shorter and copy them again.

Comment: you are right (I have checked both parameters with my hard drives (crypted in a LVM)), but my path is just 215 (iincl. filename) chars long. What is going wrong here in Ubuntu 22.04 with Nautilus, Thunderbird and co?

Comment: [UPDATE] @Raffa With ecryptfs the file name length is actually limited to just 143 chars, see [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs/32834#32834)

Answer (score 0):

seems if you use onedrive,
you manipulate the folder in the browser gui,
the onedrive sync tool installed locally could evade this error and still successfully finish the copy paste operation.